# Is satisfactory Eclipse CDT debugging on Windows possible?

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I am playing with Eclipse CDT for cross-platform development of a C++ project that has traditionally been developed in Visual Studio (currently 2008). On Linux, CDT is awesome: code navigation, debugging, etc. are almost as good as they are for Java. I was very excited to try it on Windows and hopefully have an alternative to Visual Studio.

But alas, the CDT debugger just doesn't seem to work right in Windows. I'm building with CMake + MinGW, and debugging with the "MinGW gdb" debugger in Eclipse. Sometimes it stops executing and I have to type gdb commands into the console to get it to continue; frequently it skips breakpoints altogether... (Note that MinGW's gdb seems to work 100% fine from the console, exactly as I would expect).

I am not looking for someone to solve these problems for me, but rather to tell me whether it is worth pursuing. Has someone gotten satisfactory results debugging C++ code in Eclipse CDT on Windows?

Comment: Actually, Eclipse CDT debugger is not that powerful as one may expect. It doesn't show up values in proper format when using with STLs data types also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last year, I've switched to Code:Blocks. It allows you to create separate configurations for each platform. Supports all the typical things you'd expect from an IDE. It also integrates with MinGW. It's available on Windows, Mac (not well supported), and Linux.

Comment: Almost 2 months later and I've soured on Code:Blocks because of issues I've had debugging programs on linux. I've recently switched to NetBeans. It is still actively supported receiving periodic updates.